# Yellow warning: Conditional cast from 'AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer' to 'AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer' always succeeds

Tags: swift, xcode, camera

I have this bit of code and it's throwing a yellow warning. I can't work out how to code it so the yellow warning goes away. Trying to clean up my code after converting from Swift-2 -> 3 -> 4.

```
if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) as? AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
    previewLayer.bounds = imageView.bounds
    previewLayer.position = CGPoint(x: 140, y: 140)
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    imageView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    view.addSubview(imageView)    
}
```

Removing `as? AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` shows an error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer'

Comment: just remove the conditional cast.`let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)` the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session:)` initializer it is not fallible and casting from AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer is pointless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)` always returns an object of type `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`, not of type `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?` (i.e. the returned object is not an optional and so it can't be nil).

When you do `if let`, Swift expects an Optional type. Since no optional type is created, the error occurs.

My suggestion is to remove the `if` part and just have

```
let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
previewLayer.bounds = imageView.bounds
previewLayer.position = CGPoint(x: 140, y: 140)
previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
imageView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Hope this helps!